# AppMobi, html5 sound working on simulator and android but not in iphone

Tags: javascript, html, appmobi

Today I get started in appmobi. I was developing a small example to deal with sounds.

I just needed to create a handler to play and stop many sounds.

```
var audioOn = new Audio('sounds/11.mp3'); 
audioOn.play();
```

This code is working in the xdk simulator, also on android devices, but not in my Iphone 5.

The thing is, if I use  tag it works on iphone, but I want to use javascript native api to deal with sounds and more.

I have been trying to deal with it with appmobi player library but it comes without controls to stop, resume etc, thats way I want to use native.

Here is part of javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* This function runs once the page is loaded, but appMobi is not yet active */
var init = function(){
var alarmButton = document.getElementById("alarmButton");
var on = false;
//var audioOn = new Audio('http://rpg.hamsterrepublic.com/wiki-images/3/3e/Heal8-Bit.ogg');

var audioOn = new Audio('sounds/11.mp3'); 
audioOn.addEventListener('ended', function() {
this.play();
}, false);

var but = function(){
alert("but");
alert(on);
alert(audioOn);

if(!on){
on = true;
audioOn.currentTime = 0;
audioOn.play(); 
}
else{
on = false;
audioOn.pause(); 
}
}
//alarmButton.addEventListener("click",but,false);
alarmButton.addEventListener("touchstart",but,false);
alarmButton.addEventListener("tap",but,false);

};

window.addEventListener("load",init,false);

/* This code prevents users from dragging the page */
var preventDefaultScroll = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
window.scroll(0,0);
return false;
};
document.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefaultScroll, false);

/* This code is used to run as soon as appMobi activates */
var onDeviceReady=function(){
//Size the display to 768px by 1024px
AppMobi.display.useViewport(768,1024);
//hide splash screen
AppMobi.device.hideSplashScreen(); 
};

document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);

function echo(){
alert("clicked");
}

</script>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: please see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600878/audio-in-html-of-ios-webview-control-doesnot-work/28601508#28601508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like its not appmobi issue.

I think appmobi lab app for iphone uses safari mobile to run the html5 tests.

So its a safari mobile affair.

It seems play() work when launched by an onclick event. See http://groups.google.com/group/iphonewebdev/browse_thread/thread/91e31ba7ae25e6d4?hl=en

Need to perform some tests...

Comment: Yes, the Intel JavaScript API (http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/jsAPI/index.html) is only available from the context of a mobile hybrid app built with the Cloud Build system.  If you were to run that Web code in Mobile Safari it will not have access to the appMobi library object.

Answer (score 0):

I have to try this:

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

> Supporting HTML5 audio can be tedious in modern browsers, let alone
>   legacy ones. With real-world visitors using browsers ranging from
>   mobile Safari to IE 6 across a wide range of devices, there can be
>   many support cases to consider.
>
> SoundManager 2 gives you a single, powerful API that supports both new
>   and old, using HTML5 audio where supported and optional Flash-based
>   fallback where needed. Ideally when using SoundManager 2, audio "just
>   works."