# Audio in html of ios webview control doesnot work

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, audio, uiwebview

I have included a audio tag in html and i am loading the html inside the UIWebview control. The audio plays when i click on the play button. But when i put the phone in silent mode it stops playing and instead goes on mute.

I want the audio to play even when the phone is in silent mode.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add below code:-

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

IF you want to run audio even if app is in background mode than use below code in **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOpitons**:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

**applicationDidEnterBackground:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Hope, now this will help you.

Comment: hi shreyanash i have tried doing that already. It doesnt help either.

Comment: If it works than accept and upvote answer, if you want.